# Json group array with a node value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, json.net

I have a json with below structure.

```
{
  "root": {
    "students": [
      {
        "student": {
          "Id": "1",
          "Name": "abc"
        },
        "Type": "Update",
        "Time": "20220520050003Z"
      },
      {
        "student": {
          "Id": "2",
          "Name": "def"
        },
        "Type": "Update",
        "Time": "20220520050009Z"
      },
      {
        "student": {
          "Id": "3",
          "Name": "ghi"
        },
        "Type": "Create",
        "Time": "20220520050021Z"
      },
      {
        "student": {
          "Id": "1",
          "Name": "abc"
        },
        "Type": "Create",
        "Time": "20220520050024Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to read the `students` json array and group them which has same `Id` under `student` object

For example Id 1 has two entries

```
{
        "student": {
          "Id": "1",
          "Name": "abc"
        },
        "Type": "Update",
        "Time": "20220520050003Z"
}
```

and

```
{
        "student": {
          "Id": "1",
          "Name": "abc"
        },
        "Type": "Create",
        "eventTime": "20220520050024Z"
}
```

So I want to group them based on same id and get a list of objects which has record for each unique Id.

I tried with newtonsoft linq , but not able to group them with Id value. I want to know how i can group them

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonasstring);
JObject objRoot = (JObject)obj.SelectToken("root");
var studentsList = from students in objRoot["students"]
                      select students["student"];
```

Answer (score 2):

On your example you have different property names("Time", "eventTime") - I assumed that "Time" is a correct one.

Below you can see how grouping was done:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonasstring);
JObject objRoot = (JObject)obj.SelectToken("root");
var studentsList = from students in objRoot["students"]
                   group students by students["student"]["Id"] into studentsgroup
                   select new { StudentId = studentsgroup.Key, Students = studentsgroup.Select(x => new {StudentName = x["student"]["Name"], Type = x["Type"], Time = x["Time"]})};
```

You get students list, group it by studentId and do selection as you need.

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select all objects in the `students` JSON array, then use Linq's GroupBy to bucket them by the `student.Id` property.

```
var studentsGroupedById = JObject.Parse(jsonasstring)
    .SelectTokens("$.root.students[*]")
    .GroupBy(x => x["student"]["Id"]);
```

In each group, `Key` is the `student.Id` property, and you can enumerate through all the entries in the group (the inner foreach loop).

[Runnable online version that prints out results to demonstrate the groups](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JbLKhy)

---

I corrected what I hope is a typo in your JSON - the first student entry has a `Time` property, not an `eventTime` property. If that's actually how the data is formatted you'll need to account for it.